# How to prevent caching of music in Gingerbread?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, music-player, cache, media-files

I'm using android 2.3.6. It automatically caches all the music that I add. This kind of annoys me because every time I delete a song the name of the song still appears in the music list. Therefore every time I make any changes I have to clear data from the Media App. I've been doing this for a long time and now I've had enough of it. Can someone tell me how to prevent auto caching of media files?

Answer (score 1):

Very unlikely. That's the MediaScanner's responsibility. For faster access it scans all directories on given events (e.g. SDCard mounted, boot_completed) and stores the results in a database, where most players pick it up from.

So you can either use a tool like e.g. [SDrescan](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bero.sdrescan) to trigger the *MediaPlayer*'s scan whenever you've manipulated files -- or find yourself a music player that doesn't use Android's media database but rather works e.g. folder based.